# Call to undefined function curl_errorno(), but cURL is installed and works

Tags: php, curl, php-5.3, libcurl

I am trying to get at the cURL error number, but the [`curl_errorno()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) doesn't seem to work.  If I make a one-line script:

```
curl_errorno();
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined function curl_errorno()...

- cURL is installed... I can use it to make requests just fine.
- PHP 5.3.6 (as reported by php.ini)
- cURL 7.19.7 (as reported by php.ini)
- My configure command contained `--with-curl`

Any thoughts as to why `curl_errorno()` isn't available?

Comment: `curl_errno()` is the actual name of the function, try that.

Comment: @drew010, HA!  That was it!  I have no idea how I missed that after checking it about 5 times.  Please post that as your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help that the PHP manual transparently redirects you to the correct function.  I had to double check that it wasn't an old alias.  Time for coffee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
curl_errno();
```

not

```
curl_errorno();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

To use it...

```
print curl_download('http://www.example.org/');
```

Maybe give that a try, if it works, maybe its an issue with your previous code?

Comment: Mark's answer was fine.  I was using `curl_errorno` instead of `curl_error`.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Haha - glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any Problem with CURL or CURL extension is not Install on your Server then Just Use Below Code

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array( 'http' => array(
        'user_agent'    => 'spider',    // who am i
        'max_redirects' => 10,          // stop after 10 redirects
        'timeout'       => 120,         // timeout on response
    ) );
    $context = stream_context_create( $options );
    $page    = @file_get_contents( $url, false, $context);

    $result  = array( );
    if ( $page != false )
        $result['content'] = $page;
    else if ( !isset( $http_response_header ) )
        return null;    // Bad url, timeout

    // Save the header
    $result['header'] = $http_response_header;

    // Get the *last* HTTP status code
    $nLines = count( $http_response_header );
    for ( $i = $nLines-1; $i >= 0; $i-- )
    {
        $line = $http_response_header[$i];
        if ( strncasecmp( "HTTP", $line, 4 ) == 0 )
        {
            $response = explode( ' ', $line );
            $result['http_code'] = $response[1];
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem.  I have cURL installed, as you can see in the information posted in my question.  In addition, I already have the answer.  I was simply using the wrong function name.